# How to add multiple licenses to project.clj?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

How do I add more than one license to leiningen's project.clj (my project is dually licensed)?

Comment: The sample project.clj says a seq of licenses is supported, though that doesn't seem to be the case in code. Did you try this?

Comment: Yeah. Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If I may, why don't you submit a bug report on github about this?

Comment: @jjpe: Oh, I didn't realize it was a bug. My last bug report wasn't received kindly, but I'll submit this one, anyway.

Comment: Well TBH I'm not 100% sure it is, but there is an [issue](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/1165) on github that seems like it may be related to this.

Comment: Yep. It is. I've opened [this issue](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/1187). Apparently it's been fixed but not released yet.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue that should be posted to the project issue tracker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it is overdue, but just a summary for the benefit of the readers. The bug appears to be fixed, see https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/1166

The following `project.clj` works for me on Leiningen 2.2.0 on Java 1.7.0_09 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM:

```
(defproject justatest "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"

  :licenses [{:name "Eclipse Public License"
              :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
             {:name "Example License"
              :url "http://example.com"}]
...
```